# How to consume web service in php for android?

Tags: android

1.I am facing a big problem please help me. i prepared successfully a restful 
    web service in php but when i call him from my register fragment it didn t 
    work
    this is my registerfragment,when i click on button register it showed me this toast message:Unexpected Error occured! [Most common error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import jiji.app_forma_pro.R;
import jiji.app_forma_pro.controller.Controler;

/**
 * Created by jiji on 12/05/2017.
 */

public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    TextView errorMsg;
    EditText reg_email;
    EditText reg_password;
    EditText reg_password_confirm;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView loginScreen;
    public RegisterFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Inscription");
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.activity_register, container, false);
        // Set view to register.xml
        reg_email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        reg_password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        reg_password_confirm = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reg_password_confirm);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(rootView.getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Veillez patientez..");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        btnRegister = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Register);
        loginScreen = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // On récupère les valeurs et on les convertit en string
                String email = reg_email.getText().toString();
                String password = reg_password.getText().toString();
                String password_confirm = reg_password_confirm.getText().toString();
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                // On teste si les champs login et password sont vides
                if (Controler.isNotNull(email) && Controler.isNotNull(password) && Controler.isNotNull(password_confirm)) {
                    if (Controler.validate(email)) {
                        params.put("username", email);
                        params.put("password", password);
                        params.put("password_confirm", password_confirm);
                        invokeWS(params);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Veillez entrer un email valide!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Veillez remplir tous les champs!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            private void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
                progressDialog.show();
                // Make restfull webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.get("http://127.0.0.1/webservice_formapro/client.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                    //when the response returned by REST has Http response code '200'
                    public void onSuccess(String response){
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        try {

                            //JSON Object
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            //when the json response has status boolean value assignedwith true
                            if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                                setDefaultValues();
                                Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "succes d'inscription", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                errorMsg.setText(obj.getString("error_msg"));
                                Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), obj.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Context context = rootView.getContext();
                            CharSequence text = "Error Occured [server's JSON response might be invalid]!.";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                            Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // when the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content){
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Requested ressource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Unexpected Error occured! [Most common error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment Login;
                Login = new LoginFragment();

                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_main,Login);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }


        });

        return rootView;
    }


private void setDefaultValues() {
    reg_email.setText("");
    reg_password.setText("");
    reg_password_confirm.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an error message that _you_ wrote. It doesn't carry very much useful information. Try outputting, or at least logging, the HTTP status code instead of just printing a generic message.

Comment: how to output the http status i didn't understand ,please help me it s so urgent!!

Comment: Your urgency is your own problem. We're almost all volunteers. Now, have a look at your code, which you presumably wrote. Do you see where you create the toast you're askung about? That happens when `statusCode` isn't 200, 404 or 500. It could be anything else, and its value will reveal more about what's happening. Have a look at `statusCode` there, either by logging its value, using a debugger, changing your toast text to include the status code, etc.

Comment: But the status code how can he help me to solve the problem because it returned 0??

Comment: That doesn't sound right: 0 isn't a [valid HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). I guess you're using [this library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)? What values do `error` and `string` have? (Please take a little bit of initiative here; it's _your_ code that's broken. Why didn't you bother to look at these values before?)

Comment: progressDialog = {ProgressDialog@830033427728} 
content = null
error = {HttpHostConnectException@830034273832} "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused"
statusCode = 0
this = {RegisterFragment$1$1@830034222808} 
progressDialog = {ProgressDialog@830033427728}

Comment: i copied those variables from debugger and as u see the statuscode has the value 0 and i don't know why?

Comment: The `error` very clearly tells you that the connection to 127.0.0.1 was refused. Are you using the correct port?

Comment: i am newbie in android i always try to push my app for the best i just copied the URL of my web service and i just put it in this line code client.get("http://127.0.0.1/webservice_formapro/client.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){

Comment: That will default to port 80. Is your back-end service (PHP code) running on port 80? (Note that it is common for development instances to run on another port, e.g. 8000 or 8080, though it could literally be anything.)

Comment: i checked php configuration and i found

Comment: mysql.default_port = 3307

Comment: …that's not relevant. That's the port for your _database_ server. What port is your _web_ server running on? Can you access it in a browser?

Comment: yes i can access it by just typing 127.0.0.1

Comment: Simply going to http://127.0.0.1/webservice_formapro/client.php in your browser works? Does it work in the browser on your Android device, too? Where is your Android application running? In an emulator? On a physical device? Note that 127.0.0.1 will _not_ work if your Android app is running on a different system from your PHP application (and might not work even if they're the same).

Comment: yes that address works 127.0.0.1/webservice_formapro/client.php in my browser and i tried to run my android app in emulator and on my device and as a result when i press register button it showed me the same error message

Comment: but how can i run my php app in my device?? i have no idea

Comment: You _shouldn't_ run it on your Android device. You need to run the service in a way that it can be accessed from another machine. This may be as simple as substituting 127.0.0.1 with your public IP address (at least for now), or it may be more complicated. How are you running your PHP service?